# How to understand the definition of Borel σ-algebra in $R^d$

Tags: real-analysis

How to understand the definition of Borel σ-algebra in $R^d$ which it states that $B_{R^d}$ is the intersection of all σ-algebras that contain the open sets.
My question is: I know σ-algebra sets is closed under countable intersections, but how to show that all subset of the σ-algebras above is countable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably confusing two things.

---

1) A $\sigma$-algebra is closed under *countable* intersections.

That means that: $$A_n\in\mathcal A\text{ for }n=1,2,\dots\implies\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\in\mathcal A$$ where $\mathcal A$ denotes a $\sigma$-algebra.

---

2) If $\mathcal A_i$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on the same space for every $i\in I$ then also $\bigcap_{i\in I}\mathcal A_i$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on that space.

For this it is *not required* that $I$ is *countable*.

---

In your question we are dealing with the second case.

Comment: For the second case, How to prove that if $B$ is a subset of $\bigcap_{i\in I}\mathcal A_i$ ,so is $B^C$.

Comment: You cannot prove that (and don't have to). Actually it must be proved that if $B$ is an **element** of $\bigcap_{i\in I}\mathcal A_i$ then also $B^{\complement}$ is an **element** of $\bigcap_{i\in I}\mathcal A_i$.

Comment: Sorry,that is actually what I want to ask.

Comment: If $B\in\bigcap_{i\in I}\mathcal A_i$ then $B\in\mathcal A_i$ for every $i\in I$. Then also $B^{\complement}\in\mathcal A_i$ for every $i\in I$, since every $\mathcal A_i$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Then $B^{\complement}\in\bigcap_{i\in I}\mathcal A_i$.

Comment: I see.Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome.